# Angular bootstrap modal toggle checked for data already present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly i apologize for a lengthy question as i cant post a plunker because this has services which brings data from a backend. Hence i posted as much data as i can as samples.

I have an angular js app that uses bootstrap. I have a modal defined which has the following table:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="float:left;width:525px;">
    <div class="panel-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example" data-offset="0" style="height:200px;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
        <table class="table table-hover checkbox">
            <tr>    
                <th>Course</th> 
                <th>Title</th>      
                <th>Credits</th>  
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="child in requirements">
                {% verbatim %}
                <td class="vcenter">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="" ng-click="toggleCheck(child)" ng-disabled="required == (planned + completed) && (selectedCourses.indexOf(child) == -1)" value=""/>
                                            {{child.course.subject}}-{{child.course.course_no}}
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter">{{child.course.course_name}}</td>
                    {% endverbatim %}
                <td class="vcenter">3</td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is how i defined its javascript:

```
    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function (MpttService, PlannedService, RequirementsService, $scope, $http, $log, $modalInstance, mpttid, mpttrequired, mpttcompleted, mpttplanned) {
        //debugger
        $scope.subcategory = mpttid;
        $scope.selectedCourses= [];
        $scope.completed = mpttcompleted;
        $scope.required = mpttrequired;
        $scope.planned = mpttplanned;

        MpttService.getMptt(function(data){
            $scope.mpttdetails = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        PlannedService.getPlanned(function(data){
            $scope.planneddetails = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        RequirementsService.getRequirements($scope.subcategory,function(data){
            $scope.requirements = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        angular.forEach(mpttid.subcategory, function(item) {
          $scope.selectedCourses.push(item.requirements);
        });

        $scope.getPercentage = function () {
            return (($scope.planned+$scope.completed)/($scope.required)*100).toFixed(2);
        }

        $scope.toggleCheck = function (course) {
                if (($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course) === -1)) {
                    $scope.selectedCourses.push(course);
                    $scope.planned += 3;    
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedCourses.splice($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course), 1);
                    $scope.planned -= 3;
                }

                $scope.getPercentage();
        };

        $scope.checkedfunction = function(course){

        }

        $scope.ok = function () {
          //$scope.subcategory.subcategory2 = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedCourses.length; i++){

              //$scope.subcategory.subcategory2.push({course: $scope.selectedCourses[i], term:"--",credit:"--",grade:"--"});
              var variablesToSend = {
                                    "student": 2773951,
                                    "category": $scope.subcategory,
                                    "course_name": ($scope.selectedCourses[i].course.subject).concat("-",$scope.selectedCourses[i].course.course_no),
                                    "title": $scope.selectedCourses[i].course.title,
                                    "credit": 3,
                                    "term": 'none',
                                    }
                $http.post('/api/studentplannedcredit/', variablesToSend).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    //alert('post added');
                    document.location.reload(true);

                }, function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('Unable to add Course');
                });
            }
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };
```

In this app, when the modal opens, the user can check the courses he wants and save them using the `save()` function. Since there are limitations on the number of courses to be taken, the table will disable automatically when the required number of courses have been checked.

This is how my json looks like:

Planneddetails:

```
[
    {
        "student": 2773951, 
        "category": 163, 
        "course_name": "HIST-1301", 
        "title": "History of the United States I", 
        "credit": 3, 
        "term": "2014FA"
    }, 
    {
        "student": 2773951, 
        "category": 169, 
        "course_name": "ANTH-2401", 
        "title": "Physical Anthropology", 
        "credit": 3, 
        "term": "2014SU"
    }, 
    {
        "student": 2773951, 
        "category": 169, 
        "course_name": "ENVR-1402", 
        "title": "Environmental Science II", 
        "credit": 3, 
        "term": "2015SU"
    }, 
    {
        "student": 2773951, 
        "category": 157, 
        "course_name": "HIST-1302", 
        "title": "History of the United States II", 
        "credit": 3, 
        "term": "none"
    }
]
```

MpttDetails:

```
{
        "student_program": {
            "academic_program": {
                "id": 596, 
                "program_title": "Associate in Sciences Degree", 
                "required_credits": 60
            }, 
            "id": 3685, 
            "student": 2773951, 
            "credits_completed": 26, 
            "academic_program_gpa": null, 
            "primary_program": true
        }, 
        "category": {
            "id": 163, 
            "name": "CRITICAL READING AND WRITING", 
            "min_credit": 6, 
            "parent": {
                "id": 162, 
                "name": "TIER 1 - CORE FOUNDATIONS", 
                "min_credit": 13, 
                "parent": {
                    "id": 149, 
                    "academic_program": null, 
                    "name": "AS.SCIENCE", 
                    "min_credit": 60, 
                    "max_credit": null, 
                    "parent": 128, 
                    "lft": 30, 
                    "rght": 71, 
                    "tree_id": 2, 
                    "level": 1
                }, 
                "level": 2
            }, 
            "level": 3
        }, 
        "student_academic_credit": {
            "accad_credit_id": 29328778, 
            "course": 81, 
            "student": 2773951, 
            "course_name": "ENGL-1301", 
            "title": "Composition I", 
            "credit": 3, 
            "final_grade": "C", 
            "term": "2012FA"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "student_program": {
            "academic_program": {
                "id": 596, 
                "program_title": "Associate in Sciences Degree", 
                "required_credits": 60
            }, 
            "id": 3685, 
            "student": 2773951, 
            "credits_completed": 26, 
            "academic_program_gpa": null, 
            "primary_program": true
        }, 
        "category": {
            "id": 154, 
            "name": "CB050", 
            "min_credit": 3, 
            "parent": {
                "id": 152, 
                "name": "HUMANITY, CREATIVITY AND THE AESTHETIC EXPERIENCE", 
                "min_credit": 6, 
                "parent": {
                    "id": 150, 
                    "academic_program": null, 
                    "name": "TIER 2 - CORE DOMAINS", 
                    "min_credit": 26, 
                    "max_credit": null, 
                    "parent": 149, 
                    "lft": 41, 
                    "rght": 60, 
                    "tree_id": 2, 
                    "level": 2
                }, 
                "level": 3
            }, 
            "level": 4
        }, 
        "student_academic_credit": {
            "accad_credit_id": 29328777, 
            "course": 209, 
            "student": 2773951, 
            "course_name": "ARTS-1301", 
            "title": "Art Apprec", 
            "credit": 3, 
            "final_grade": "A", 
            "term": "2012FA"
        }
    },
```

and my Requirements json:

```
[
    {
        "category": 163, 
        "course": {
            "course_id": 1023, 
            "subject": "HIST", 
            "course_no": "1301", 
            "course_name": "History of the United States I", 
            "title": "History of the United States I", 
            "local_govt_code": "5401025125", 
            "academic_level": "CR", 
            "grade_scheme": "CR", 
            "credit_type": "I", 
            "course_type": "1", 
            "course_level": "1", 
            "min_credit": 3, 
            "max_credit": null, 
            "prereqs": 7, 
            "cip": "54.0102", 
            "ceus": "", 
            "transfer_status": "060"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "category": 163, 
        "course": {
            "course_id": 81, 
            "subject": "ENGL", 
            "course_no": "1301", 
            "course_name": "Composition I", 
            "title": "Composition I", 
            "local_govt_code": "2313015112", 
            "academic_level": "CR", 
            "grade_scheme": "CR", 
            "credit_type": "I", 
            "course_type": "1", 
            "course_level": "1", 
            "min_credit": 3, 
            "max_credit": null, 
            "prereqs": 5, 
            "cip": "23.0401", 
            "ceus": "", 
            "transfer_status": "010"
        }
    }
]
```

The next step was to check all the courses in the table that have already been taken. These details will be retrieved from the **mpttdetails** and the **planneddetails**.

So how do i make the modal open with the table having courses already checked for those which are present in the mpttdetails and planned details?

Note: the courses in the `$scope.requirements.course.{{subject}}-{{course_no}}` needs to be compared with the `mpttdetails.student_academic_credit.course_name` and the `planneddetails.course_name` . But i am unable to figure out how to achieve this. Please help!

Comment: can you reduce this to a generic question?  or at least make a plunkr with hardcoded json to simulate the response from the service?

Comment: @crozzfire: It is not clear what is the criteria for determining if something should be cacked or not and what the problem is with implementing it (e.g. why don't you have a function that receives `child.course` and determines if it should be checked ?).

Comment: Hi @j.wittwer .. I tried a function and framed the question better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959776/angular-js-toggle-data-enable-and-disable-on-check/23960274?noredirect=1#comment36915299_23960274

Comment: @ExpertSystem : i reframed the question with the function as you mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959776/angular-js-toggle-data-enable-and-disable-on-check/23960274?noredirect=1#comment36915299_23960274