# angular js toggle data enable and disable on check

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the an angular app which has the following toggle table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in requirements">
    <td class="vcenter">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkedfunction(child)" ng-click="toggleCheck(child)" ng-disabled="required == (planned + completed) && (selectedCourses.indexOf(child) == -1)" value=""/>
    {{child.course.subject}}-{{child.course.course_no}}
    </td>
    <td class="vcenter">{{child.course.course_name}}</td>}
    <td class="vcenter">3</td> 
</tr>
```

And the controller app.js has the following function:

```
    $scope.toggleCheck = function (course) {
            //checkedfunction(course);
            if (($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course) === -1)) {
                $scope.selectedCourses.push(course);
                $scope.planned += 3;    
            } else {
                $scope.selectedCourses.splice($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course), 1);
                $scope.planned -= 3;
            }

            $scope.getPercentage();
    };

    $scope.checkedfunction = function(course){
        //$scope.requirementcoursename = [];
        //for(var i = 0; i < $scope.requirements.length; i++){
            $scope.coursedetail = course;
            $scope.requirementcoursename = ($scope.coursedetail.course.subject).concat("-",$scope.coursedetail.course.course_no);
            for(var j = 0; j < $scope.mpttdetails.length; j++){
                if($scope.requirementcoursename==$scope.mpttdetails[j].student_academic_credit.course_name){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            for(var k = 0; k < $scope.planneddetails.length; k++){
                if($scope.requirementcoursename==$scope.planneddetails[k].course_name){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        //} 

    }
```

Here, the toggle will be checked if the courses are already present in any of the data arrays as seen in the `checkedfunction()`.

But i would like to know if there is a way to disable the courses being checked in the `mpttdetails` and keep the `planneddetails` enabled?

i am trying to check and disable the toggle(just like how i am doing it in the ng-checked) if the child is present in mpttdetails(ie it returns true when the check is performed on the mpttdetails loop). If not it will just stay checked and enabled

Comment: I think I'm confused about what you're getting at because my first response was "just delete the for loop that checks mpttdetails. Can you further describe what you're trying to change?

Comment: i am trying to check and disable the toggle(just like how i am doing it in the ng-checked) if the child is present in mpttdetails(ie it returns true when the check is performed on the mpttdetails loop). If not it will just stay checked and enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your `mpttdetails` check out of `checkFunction`, creating a new scope function:

```
$scope.checkMpttdetails = function(course) {
    ...    
}
```

That way, you can still call it from `checkedFunction`

```
$scope.checkedfunction = function(course){
    ...
    if ($scope.checkMpttdetails) { return true }
    ...
}
```

while using it in your `ng-disabled` expression

```
ng-disabled="(required == (planned + completed) && 
(selectedCourses.indexOf(child) == -1)) || checkMpttdetails(child)"
```

I realize that there are additional details that will require some refactoring (e.g. how you use the passed parameters at the top of `checkedFunction`), but those are left to you.

Comment: hi...the functions are working well. But the disabling part was not working somehow..

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of `required` is meant to fulfill in the expression. Is it necessary there or can you remove it and leave just the right hand side of the expression? Do you need to equality test?

Comment: yeah it is required because i have another condition to disable the whole table after a few limited selects

Comment: It sounds like these are two independent conditions, then. Please try the expression as updated in my answer.